# function to Get array and specific start letter and end letter and then return a list of names that starts and end with them

Tags: javascript

I have a long array of objects. I want to write a function to find for example names that start with specific letter and end with another specific letter and return a list of names that starts and end with them.

I tried some solutions but did not get answer.

Here I use a simple list: and I want a list that name start with "A" and end with "i" or any other case

```
myList = [{name: "Aji",family: "Ziansi"}, { name: "Alex", family: "ortega"}, {name:"Amandi",family: "Sedirini"}];
```

Output should be like this:

```
desiredLiset = [{name: "Aji",family: "Ziansi"}, {name:"Amandi",family: "Sedirini"}];
```

**just in function declaration method.**

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I need a function declaration to get alphabet as  start and end character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Array.filter()`

```js
const myList = [{
  name: "Aji",
  family: "Ziansi"
}, {
  name: "Alex",
  family: "ortega"
}, {
  name: "Amandi",
  family: "Sedirini"
}];

const filterList = (list, start, end) => {
  return list.filter(obj => {
    const name = obj.name;
    return name[0] === start && name[name.length - 1] === end;
  });
};

const filtered = filterList(myList, "A", "i");
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: how can I edit this for all letters as a function?

Comment: You can create a function that returns another function. Sample code below:

`function createFilterFunction(startLetter, endLetter) {
    return (obj) => {
        const name = obj.name;
        return name[0] === start && name[name.length - 1] === end;
    }
}`

You would pass it into Array.filter by calling it (since calling it would produce the actual filtering function), e.g. `myList.filter(obj => createFilterFunction('A', 'i')(obj))`

Comment: @zigzag I have updated the solution and created a function which takes `list`, `start` and `end` and returns a filtered list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` to get a list of the names you want:

```
myList = [{name: "Aji",family: "Ziansi"}, { name: "Alex", family: "ortega"}, {name:"Amandi",family: "Sedirini"}];

let desiredLiset = myList.filter(function(n){
    return n.name.match(/^A.*i$/i) // Names that begin with 'A' and end with 'i'
});

console.log(desiredLiset)
// 0: Object { name: "Aji", family: "Ziansi" }
// ​1: Object { name: "Amandi", family: "Sedirini" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myList = [{name: "Aji",family: "Ziansi"}, { name: "Alex", family: "ortega"}, {name:"Amandi",family: "Sedirini"}];

const start='A'
const end='i'
const startEndRE = new RegExp(`^${start}.*${end}$`)
myList.filter(item=>(
    startEndRE.test(item.name)
))

// Result 
// [
//   { name: 'Aji', family: 'Ziansi' },
//   { name: 'Amandi', family: 'Sedirini' }
// ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do using endsWith() and startsWith()

try:

```
const myList = [{ name: "Aji", family: "Ziansi" }, { name: "Alex", family: "ortega" }, { name: "Amandi", family: "Sedirini" }];

const newlist = myList.filter((obj) => obj.name.startsWith('A') && obj.name.endsWith('i'));

console.log(newlist);
```